# jquery enable and disable elements based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button when clicked it disables a user from clicking anything on an element so something like this:

```
$( "#buttonid" ).click(function() {
   $("#test").css("pointer-events","none");
});
```

But once the user leaves the page and comes back the element is clickable again. How do I maintain the status to keep it unclickable?

Comment: Use `sessionStorage` or `cookies`

Comment: store in `localStorage`

Comment: This depends on your design. You could do session or cookie variables, but if this is a permanent change you may want to consider a database value.

Comment: I think I would do database storage. I was thinking maybe it could be done. But yeah Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Session or a Cookie.

Comment: While this does theoretically answer the OP's question, a good Stack Overflow answer should expand on the solution with a "why should I use this solution" and some code.